# Running exe file gives "failed to execute script main" after pyi build

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have quite a large application written in Python 3 on Ubuntu. I have made many successful ports to Windows and used pyi build to create an exe file.

I have made significant changes to the code, including making packages of certain modules. It still runs on windows if I use

```
python main.py
```

But now, if I create an exe file with pyi build, I get the error:

```
failed to execute script main
```

I have tried to isolate the problem but without success, there seem to be many points at which the code fails

I know that I cannot expect a definitive solution to this problem, but any pointers to possible causes of the issue will be sincerely appreciated.

[More information, 2 Apr 18]

A sufficient cause for a pyi-build exe to fail is related to the __init__.py file.

I have a test directory with the files:

```
a.py
\__init__.py
main.py
pyi.spec
```

If I have the file __init__.py in the project directory it fails; if I remove it, it does not fail:

main.py:

```
from a import A
```

a.py

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

__init__.py (empty)

pyi.spec

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
a.datas = list({tuple(map(str.upper, t)) for t in a.datas})
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='test_for_fail.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False)
```

However, if I remove __init__.py from my real project directory, it still fails, so there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the packages that I created and placed them in the same folder as the main.py. I don't know why

```
python main.py worked
```

and the pyinstaller exe failed.

This is not the complete answer, but it certainly contributed to the problem